# Find word with N non-consecutive instances of a certain character?

Tags: python, regex

I want to find a unique ID in a string:

`text = "Hello World, aaaa_dddd_bbbb_cccc"`

The only defining feature of the unique ID is that it is a single word that contains three underscores. However, for the life of me I can't even start of figure out the regex for matching words with N non-consecutive instances of a certain character.

The best I can do is a hacky use of `.split()`:

```
unique_id = None

for word in text.split(' '):
    if len(word.split("_")) > 2:
        unique_id = word
```

Comment: `The only defining feature of the unique ID is that it is a single word that contains three underscores` This is a problem. Also, what do you mean by this statement `matching words with N non-consecutive instances of a certain character` ? If it's like all a's `aaaa` then all d's `dddd`, then that would be something like `\b([^\W_])\1+_([^\W_])\2+_([^\W_])\3+_([^\W_])\4+\b`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> text = "Hello World, aaaa_dddd_bbbb_cccc"

>>> re.search(r'([a-z]+_[a-z]+){3}', text)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(13, 32), match='aaaa_dddd_bbbb_cccc'>
```

The pattern matches one or more word characters followed by an underscore follwed by one or more word characters, three times.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

> {m}
>
> Specifies that exactly m copies of the previous RE should be matched; fewer matches cause the entire RE not to match. For example, a{6} will match exactly six 'a' characters, but not five.

Comment: Woah, I've never seen that `{3}` usage before. Thanks!

Comment: Nothing proves that characters are not consecutive.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Good to see SO isn't toxic.

Answer (score 1):

With straightforward regex pattern:

```
import re

s = "Hello World, aaaa_dddd_bbbb_cccc"
m = re.search(r'\b([^_\s]+_){3}[^_\s]+\b', s)
result = m.group() if m else m

print(result)
```

The output:

```
aaaa_dddd_bbbb_cccc
```

---

The pattern could be more strict (depends on what characters are allowed) like:

```
...
m = re.search(r'\b([a-z0-9]+_){3}[a-z0-9]+\b', s, re.I)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex `findall` to get a list of all items that match eg:

```
text = "Hello World, aaaa_dddd_bbbb_cccc, 1_2_3_4"

import re
found = re.findall(r'[^_ ]*_[^_ ]+_[^_ ]+_[^_ ]*',text)

print(found)
# -> ['aaaa_dddd_bbbb_cccc,', '1_2_3_4']
```

This allows strings starting and ending with a `_` eg `_1_2_3` if you don't want that you can change the first and last `*` to a `+`